# catkin 'ized' Vicon Package

Tags: ros, catkin, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings, I am looking for a recent vicon interface node and have not found a stable one. The following link,

http://answers.ros.org/question/11456/vicon-motion-capturing-which-ros-package-is-the-best/#

lists three, where 2 are old versions / non-catkinized and 1 no longer exists in the wiki.

Any suggestions as to where I can find an updated vicon data publishing node?

Regards,

Jim

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200682/catkin-%27ized%27-vicon-package/) by [101010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3108/101010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand you correctly, this has been answered before. See [vicon with ROS INDIGO](http://answers.ros.org/question/199701/vicon-with-ros-indigo/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0